# spockframework grouping tests by environment

Tags: groovy, spock

I am doing a bunch of integration tests using Spock and I would like to group by test by the target environment.
What is the idiomatic Spock why of group test by target by target environment or set of conditions ?
Thank you
 Luis Oscar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the @IgnoreIf annotation.  You can use it on classes or methods.  You would need some kind of a system property or value to indicate the environment you're running on.

ex: @IgnoreIf("${environment != 'prod'}")